# Android | The following classes could not be found: menu and item

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I'm trying to put a menu on my application, but when I put a menu tag in my xml like this:

```
<menu
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:title="Item 1">
    </item><item
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:title="Item 1">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:title="Item 1">
    </item>
</menu>
```

I get this error message when I go on the graphical layout.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- item (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- menu (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
```

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to add the xml namespace:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Try this:

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:title="Item 1">
    </item><item
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:title="Item 1">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:title="Item 1">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Please note also that this file has to be stored in a seperat xml file in the menu directory in your res directory.

For using this menu in your activity add this code (I expect that your xml file is main.xml):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I added that in my relative layout. (My menu is in my relative layout, is that bad?)

Comment: That xml file has to be in a seperate file in the menu directory.

Comment: Oh I see! And how will I link the menu with my activity?

Comment: Ok perfect, there is already that code by default. Thank you, I will accept when possible.

Answer (score 0):

The menu xml files should be under the menu directory.
That why the classes cannot be found.